# Navigation hover effect

Tags: html, css, menu, navigation, hover

I have been trying to create my first `html` and `css` website, but right now I'm stuck in the navigation because I'm trying to do a hover effect in the links, what I want is when you hover a link, a box should appear over a link, this box will have a shadow, can you help me out?

Thank you!!

Here is my nav code atm:

```
<div class="row">
        <nav class="main-nav nav-js">    
        <img class="logo" src="" alt="">
          <ul>
            <li><a href="#about_us">ABOUT US</a></li>
            <li><a href="#search">SEARCH</a></li>
            <li><a href="#top_artists">TOP ARTISTS</a></li>
            <li><a href="#contacts">CONTACTS</a></li>
          </ul>
        </nav>    
        </div>
```

css:

```
.main-nav { 
background-color: #2c3136; 
width: 100%;
height: 70px; 
text-align: center; 
box-shadow: 0 0 5 0 #000; }

.main-nav  li{
    display: inline;
    list-style: none;
      }

.main-nav li a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: white;
    margin-right: 50px;
    font-size: 90%;
    font-weight:  bold;
      }

.main-nav li a:link
.main-nav li a:visited {
    padding: 8 0;
    color: #fff;
    background: transparent;
    transition: background 0.3s ease-in-out;
}


.main-nav li a:hover, 
.main-nav li a:active {
    color: #fff;
    background: #5a5a5a;
    transition: background 0.3s ease-in-out;
}
```

Example of what I want: https://w3layouts.com/preview/?l=/boombox-a-entertainment-category-flat-bootstrap-responsive-template/

Comment: Insert your actual code here, not just a picture. It's hard to help otherwise.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself** preferably in a [**Stack Snippet**](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/).  See [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a code snippet with your intended behavior:

```css
.main-nav {
  background-color: #2c3136;
  width: 100%;
  height: 70px;
  text-align: center;
  box-shadow: 0 0 5 0 #000;
}

.main-nav li {
  display: inline;
  list-style: none;
}

.main-nav li a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: white;
  margin-right: 50px;
  font-size: 90%;
  font-weight: bold;
  padding: 4px;
  border-radius: 4px;
}

.main-nav li a:link .main-nav li a:visited {
  padding: 8 0;
  color: #fff;
  background: transparent;
  transition: background 0.3s ease-in-out;
}

.main-nav li a:hover,
.main-nav li a:active {
  color: #fff;
  background: #5a5a5a;
  box-shadow: 4px 4px 4px #000;
  transition: background 0.3s ease-in-out;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <nav class="main-nav nav-js">
    <img class="logo" src="" alt="">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#about_us">ABOUT US</a></li>
      <li><a href="#search">SEARCH</a></li>
      <li><a href="#top_artists">TOP ARTISTS</a></li>
      <li><a href="#contacts">CONTACTS</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</div>
```

I added `padding: 4px;` and `border-radius: 4px;` to your `.main-nav li a` selector and I added `box-shadow: 4px 4px 4px #000;` to your `.main-nav li a:hover, .main-nav li a:active` selector. I hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you so much mate!
It helped!

Answer (score 0):

Have you something like this?

```
nav ul li a:hover {
  background-color: #333333;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  box-shadow: 2px 10px 8px #888888;
}
```

Comment: But here where do you set the width ad the height of the box?

Comment: you can add padding around text to fill the area around it.